# How do I have a Headers folder in Code::Blocks?

Tags: directory, codeblocks, header-files

I am using Code::Blocks 17.12 on Windows, and would like to create a folder to house the header files.

By default, when I create a console project, a Sources folder is created virtually (there isn't such a folder on disk, but it appears as such in Code::Blocks in the Management window's Project tab.

How do I create additional folders? When I right-click on the project (in the Management window's Project tab), I don't see a way to create a folder.

Answer (score 0):

After Googling around for a bit, I came across this post, although dated 2009:
http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=11365.0

Combining that answer with mine, these are the steps for creating a folder in Code::Blocks:

1. On your disk (i.e. outside of Code::Blocks), create your folders and add any existing files that you need to it. In my case I created an `Includes` folder and copied existing .h files into it.
2. Right-click on the project name in the Management windows' Project tab, and choose `Project tree`. Tick the `Display folders as disk` option.
3. Right-click on the project name again, and choose `Add files recursively...`.
4. A dialog box appears. Navigate to your subfolder and click OK. Another dialog box appears asking you to select the files to add to the project. By default all the files in the subfolder are selected, so click OK.
5. The folder will appear in Code::Blocks, under a folder called `Headers`.
6. You will also need to add the folder(s) that you created outside of Code::Blocks to the compiler's search directories by clicking on `Settings -> Compiler...`. Then click on the `Search directories` tab, select the `Compiler` tab, then click Add.
7. In the dialog box that appears, click on the folder icon and navigate to your folder. Then click OK.